PATCH forms/:formid endpoint with C# .net class
Autodesk Construction Cloud - Build - submit form - with C# .net class.
This guide includes form submit:
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/tutorials/forms/create-update-forms/
Is there an Autodesk .NET NuGet package that includes this method?
I am new to the httpclient and Newtonsoft.
Havent figured out how to represent the CURL provided with C#. Is there an example available?
Thank You.
K.

This worked for me...
var content = new StringContent("{\"status\":\"submitted\"}", `Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");`
string url = $"https://developer.api.autodesk.com/construction/forms/v1/projects/{projectid}/form-templates/{templayeid}/forms/{formid}";
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AccessTokenV);
var PA = new HttpMethod("PATCH");
var req = new HttpRequestMessage(PA, url) { Content = content};
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(req);

